# How to use the UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt> in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3, containers, mutable, unsafemutablepointer

```
if let fileObject = NSString(contentsOfFile: strBundle, usedEncoding:Int32?
```

Every time that I try to work this out, I get more frustrated! Please help me! I am not sure what I need to fill in the "usedEncoding:" parameter.

Here is the error it gives me:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int32?.Type' (aka
>   'Optional.Type') to expected argument type
>   'UnsafeMutablePointer?'

Comment: If that's the case, then do you have any ideas on how I can fix it?

Comment: Could you add more code in the snippet?

Comment: Why are you using Foundation methods instead of Swift methods?  Why not use `String(contentsOfFile:)` which `throws` its error?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
let f = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myFile", withExtension: "txt")!
var enc : String.Encoding = .ascii // dummy value
let s = try! String(contentsOf: f, usedEncoding: &enc)
```

Modify as needed (e.g. use a real `try` in a `do/catch` construct etc.); the example code is just to get you going again.

Comment: Good to see an answer in swift, rather than ***Foundation***